# subtract list of lists from list of lists with conditional arguments

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements, nested-lists, subtraction

I have sort of a tricky problem that I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around.

I have two lists of lists:

```
firstList = [[0, 9], [0, 4], [0]]
secondList = [[18], [19, 7], [20]]
```

I would like to subtract the value(s) in `firstList` from the values in `secondList` in ascending order but *only* if the values in `firstList` haven't already been "used".  For example:

```
thirdList = [0,4]
fourthList = [19,7]
emptyList = []

emptyList.append(fourthList-thirdList]
print(emptyList)
>>>[7,3]
```

In this case, `19` wasn't used because there were no values in thirdList between the previous value in fourthList and `19`

I'm thinking something like this (although it quickly decomposes into pseudocode)

```
firstList = [[0, 9], [0, 4], [0]]
secondList = [[18], [19, 7], [20]]
emptyList = [ [] for y in range(3) ]

for x in range(3) :
    #for smallest value in secondList[x], subtract all smaller values in firstList and then delete them, append values to emptyList[x]
    #for next smallest value in secondList[x], subtract all smaller values in firstList and then delete them, append values to emptyList[x]
    #repeat until firstList is empty, then exit loop

print(emptyList)
>>>[[9, 18], [3, 7], [20]]
```

this would exclude the use of `19` in secondList[1] because `0` and `4` had already been deleted after being subtracted from `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
firstList = [[0, 9], [0, 4], [0]]
secondList = [[18], [19, 7], [20]]
all_results = []

for x in range(0, len(firstList)):  
    values_of_first = firstList[x]
    values_of_second = secondList[x]
    values_of_first.sort()
    values_of_second.sort()  
    tmp_results = []

    for subtractor in values_of_second:    
        used_values = []
        for subtracted in values_of_first:
            if subtracted >= subtractor:
                break
            else:
                used_values.append(subtracted)
                tmp_results.append(subtractor - subtracted)

        for used_value in used_values:
            values_of_first.remove(used_value)

    tmp_results.sort()
    all_results.append(tmp_results)
```

It produces `all_results == [[9, 18], [3, 7], [20]]`